# OmniAuth 1.0: NoMethodError when clicking user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I'm having this problem when clicking on user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) link:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-24 10:57:03 +0200

    NoMethodError (undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass):
      omniauth (1.0.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:165:in `call!'
      omniauth (1.0.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:148:in `call'
      omniauth (1.0.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:42:in `call'
      warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
      warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
      warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
      rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
      rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
      rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
      rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
      activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
      activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
      activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2667807547873405266__call__33580566203138325__callbacks'
      activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
      activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
```

I'm currently trying to migrate to use OmniAuth 1.0 with omniauth-facebook gem. All this stuff is running with Rails 3.2.1. I was following the tutorial here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Right now I can't find anything that I did differently than in that tutorial. Still I'm getting this problem when clicking on the Facebook login button on my page.

Digging into a strategy.rb of the omniauth gem, it fails at this point:

```
return request_call if on_request_path? && OmniAuth.config.allowed_request_methods.include?(request.request_method.downcase.to_sym)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just added this to an initialization file and it seems to fix the issue.

```
OmniAuth.config.allowed_request_methods = [:post, :get]
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have found, the bug is not within the omniauth gem, but in rack. At least that's what the guys over at github have found. Check the issues:

OmniAuth: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/568

and

Rack: https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/322

I got it working when I switched from the gems to checking out the repos:

```
gem 'rack', git: 'https://github.com/rack/rack.git'
gem 'omniauth', git: 'https://github.com/intridea/omniauth.git'
```